# How to remove time part of datatimeoffset in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I searched the internet and could not find an answer for this specific problem I am dealing with.

I have a `datetimeoffset` column in a table and for the `datetimeoffset` value in each row I like to calculate the start of the day in its time zone and then convert it to my local time zone.

For instance, for a row with this value `2018-01-01 03:15:01 +08:00`, I need to get this `2018-01-01 00:00:00 +08:00` and then convert it to my local time zone. The first part looks hard, although the funny way would be to convert to text with a code that eliminates time part, and finally convert back to `datetimeoffset` maintaining the original time zone.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This would do:

select toDatetimeOffset(convert(date,dtOffsetValue), datepart(tz,dtOffsetValue))
from dbo.MyTable